# Multiple if statement to update the filed same model or change the records to another model using Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

**I am getting array value from the request and my first if statement works great to me, in the case of second if statement its migrating only one row to my salereturn table but i want all the record in the request to be migrate to the salereturn table.**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $Productsalesrec = !empty($this->request->data['Productsales']) ? $this->request->data['Productsales'] : "";

    if (!empty($Productsalesrec)) {
        foreach ($Productsalesrec as $Productsales) {

            if ($Productsales['status'] == 'MoveToShipment') {

                $this->Productsales->id = $Productsales['id'];
                $this->request->data['Productsales']['status'] = $Productsales['status'];
                $this->Productsales->save($this->request->data);
            }

            if ($Productsales['status'] == 'Returned') {

                $productsalesretArr = array();
                $productsalesre = $this->Productsales->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Productsales.product_sales_slno' => $id)));

                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['sales_order_date'] = $productsalesre['Productsales']['sales_order_date'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['product_sale_id'] = $productsalesre['Productsales']['id'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['sales_date'] = $productsalesre['Productsales']['expected_delivery_date'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['product_sales_slno'] = $productsalesre['Productsales']['product_sales_slno'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['price_per_unit_order'] = $productsalesre['Productsales']['sales_price_per_unit_order'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['total_amount'] = $productsalesre['Productsales']['sales_price_per_unit_order'] * $Productsales['tot_unit'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['total_unit'] = $Productsales['tot_unit'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['product_id'] = $Productsales['product_id'];
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['amount_returned'] = 0;
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['status'] = 'Returned';
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['payment_method'] = 'Cash on Delivery';
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['created_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['created_by'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

                $this->Salesreturn->save($this->request->data['Salesreturn']);

                if ($Productsales['total_unit'] == $Productsales['tot_unit']) {
                    $this->Productsales->delete($Productsales['id']);
                } elseif ($Productsales['total_unit'] >= $Productsales['tot_unit']) {
                    $this->Productsales->id = $Productsales['id'];
                    $this->request->data['Productsales']['total_unit'] = $Productsales['total_unit'] - $Productsales['tot_unit'];
                    $this->Productsales->save($this->request->data);
                }

                $prodtype = $this->Producttype->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Producttype.id' => $productsalesre['Productsales']['product_type_id'])));
                $this->Producttype->id = $prodtype['Producttype']['id'];

                $prodquantity = $prodtype['Producttype']['quantity'] + ($Productsales['total_unit'] - $Productsales['tot_unit']);
                $prodtotstck = $prodtype['Producttype']['total_unit_stock'] + ($Productsales['total_unit'] - $Productsales['tot_unit']);

                $this->Producttype->saveField('total_unit_stock', $prodtotstck);
                $this->Producttype->saveField('quantity', $prodquantity);
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting array value from the request and my first if statement  --> if($Productsales['status'] == 'MoveToShipment') works great to me, in the case of second if statement --> if($Productsales['status'] == 'Returned')   its migrating only one row to my salereturn table but i want all the record in the request to be migrate to the salereturn table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand the problem...

Do you mean this part of code hasn't the wanted behaviour ?

```
if($Productsales['status'] == 'Returned') {
    $this->request->data['Salesreturn']['sales_order_date']=$productsalesre['Productsales']['sales_order_date'];    
    ...
    $this->Salesreturn->save($this->request->data['Salesreturn']);
}
```

Does your condition " $Productsales['status'] == 'Returned' " is the problem ?

may be only one row of your post array has this status.

Comment: there are two if statement, first if is to update the status alone in same table, first if is not served than the second if statement has to copy all rows related to the  product_sales_slno  from the below query to another table called sales return...                                                                         $productsalesre=$this->Productsales->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Productsales.product_sales_slno' => $id)));